# Dreamweaver CS6 / SQL Server: Column IS in the Group by but still get error: Column invalid in the select list because

Tags: sql-server, asp-classic, odbc, dreamweaver, adodb

OK - Before you go to saying that this question has already been answered, look at the question again. I have googled the question and have been searching for several days to find the answer. I did not count the number of pages I reviewed in my search but is it around 200, if not more. Most of the pages are on the same theme that the programmer actually did not have the column in the group by.

My issue is a little more difficult.

Here is the code in question.

```
SELECT Type_Of_Visit, COUNT(DISTINCT Visit_ID) AS NumVisits FROM view2
WHERE (C_ID = 129) AND (Visit_Date BETWEEN '10/1/2015' AND '9/30/2016') 
GROUP BY Type_Of_Visit
```

Note the group by.

The view was created because of this issue, and is a complex view of several tables extracting four total columns.Type_Of_Visit, Visit_ID, C_ID, Visit_Date. All the columns I need to work with.

This code works just fine in SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS). However, I am using Dreamweaver CS6 (DW) to build the page and whenever I try to use the code, and try to expand the recordset in the bindings window, DW will give the error: (Actual text)

```
[Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Column 
'view2.Type_Of_Visit' is invalid in the select list because 
it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
```

Note that the indicated column IS in the group by.
Note that the code works in SSMS.
Note that similar code that has been working for years is now having the same issue.
The view extracts just fine on the page. When I aggregate COUNT(DISTINCT) DW produces the error when I expand the recordset.

I have been looking for so long that now my head hurts. I hope someone has had this issue before and can tell me what they did to get past it.

Edited slightly for clarity. G

Comment: Can you also give the definition of view2?

Comment: If _similar code that has been working for years is now having the same issue_ , it could be something wrong with your connector?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK this is driving me crazy (and it is a short drive).

After reading the posts, I changed the query in DW to be the actual query (from view2) with all the joins, etc, and it worked. I checked it out and it turns out that DW does not like local variables, which is new to me, because I have pages with 20+ recordsets on it using local variables.

As best as I can determine it must be the combination of using a local variable and an aggregation in the SQL statement. Which does not make sense to me, but the statement now works using DWs variables (__MMColPaRM).

Thanks to @Dijkgraaf for requesting the definition of the view that pointed me in the direction I needed to go.